# Rails S - Exiting and cant figure out why

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Below is the errors its throwing. I am very new to this so still learning to troubleshoot. Thanks for the help.

```
Exiting
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `load': /Users/silver2002ws6/code/omrails/app/models/model.rb:11: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end (SyntaxError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `block in load_file'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:639:in `new_constants_in'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:468:in `load_file'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:353:in `require_or_load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `block in constantize'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `constantize'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:554:in `get'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:588:in `constantize'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/devise-3.0.1/lib/devise.rb:278:in `get'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/devise-3.0.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:77:in `to'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/devise-3.0.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:72:in `modules'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/devise-3.0.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:89:in `routes'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/devise-3.0.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:156:in `default_used_route'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/devise-3.0.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:66:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/devise-3.0.1/lib/devise.rb:312:in `new'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/devise-3.0.1/lib/devise.rb:312:in `add_mapping'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/devise-3.0.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:208:in `block in devise_for'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/devise-3.0.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:207:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/devise-3.0.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:207:in `devise_for'
    from /Users/silver2002ws6/code/omrails/config/routes.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:282:in `instance_exec'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:282:in `eval_block'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:260:in `draw'
    from /Users/silver2002ws6/code/omrails/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:78:in `call'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:78:in `execute'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:66:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/silver2002ws6/code/omrails/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/silver2002ws6/code/omrails/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /Users/silver2002ws6/code/omrails/config.ru:in `new'
    from /Users/silver2002ws6/code/omrails/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
Austins-MacBook-Pro:omrails silver2002ws6$ Exiting
-bash: Exiting: command not found
Austins-MacBook-Pro:omrails silver2002ws6$ /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `load': /Users/silver2002ws6/code/omrails/app/models/model.rb:11: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end (SyntaxError)
> from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `block in load_file'
> from /usr/local/rvm/
```

Comment: You have a syntax error in file:/Users/silver2002ws6/code/omrails/app/models/model.rb at line 11.

Comment: `/Users/silver2002ws6/code/omrails/app/models/model.rb:11: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end (SyntaxError)` << I think this may be the helpful part :)

Answer (score 2):

```
Austins-MacBook-Pro:omrails silver2002ws6$ /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `load': /Users/silver2002ws6/code/omrails/app/models/model.rb:11: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end (SyntaxError)
```

Looks like you may have a syntax error in that file. FYI, having a model named `Model` is not a good idea. Consider a different name.

This particular syntax error may be because you have an extra `end` somewhere, or are missing an `end`, or because you have an `end` but are missing the `do`.

If you post your code we can help more.

Comment: class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, #:recoverable, 
         :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable


  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, 
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
end 



This is my mode.rb code

Comment: @user2690400 Can you edit your question and add the code there instead? It's pretty hard to read from the comment...

Comment: I got it to work... under attr_accessible I had not told it to recognize :name. I wont try to explain it beyond so as not to confuse any newbies like myself that may come across this. Thank you for the help!